# Can't get second brush to register on canvas using dynamic paint image sequence

Tags: modifiers, physics, dynamic-paint

Trying to paint a plane with 2 brushes at the same time, but one isn't registering on the canvas in the image sequence bake.

I'm painting one texture on top of another using image sequence. I got it to work with one brush, but even duplicating the same mesh to make the second brush wont cause the desired painting effect with the second mesh.

GIF of the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXdpq.jpg

I am sure the mesh intersects the plane, even gone so far as to group the two into a brush collection, but only one brush shows up on the canvas in the image sequence bake. Anyone know some possible causes? Can post blend files if necessary.

P.S: Below is my canvas material node layout. Bottom texture box is the grayscale texture of the image in the top texture box, while the image sequence obviously holds the baked images.

[image: Canvas texture nodes]

[image: Canvas physics settings]

[image: Settings for brush that isnt painting]

[image: Settings for brush that is painting]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. My brushes are following paths. For some reason, I couldn't copy my path over from my previous brush without it painting over the same area. I have flipped the path upside down as seen in the gif, but the paint was still occurring at the same coords, despite the brush visually moving at different coords.

Add a new path, constrain your second brush to the new path and everything works fine now.